# Trying to set up WebLogic server with OEPE but can't find WLS

Tags: eclipse, oracle, weblogic

I've downloaded `OEPE` with `Eclipse 12.2.1.5` using the packaged distribution and am now trying to work through an ADF application tutorial.

When I go to define a new server, I'm not able to select from different versions of `Oracle WebLogic Servers` (11gR1, 11gR2, etc.), the dialog box only shows a single option for "Oracle WebLogic Server".

If I select that option and try to point it to the WLS, I get the error:

> "The path ... does not contain a valid WebLogic server install or the installed version is not supported".

The WLS server version is 10.3.6.

I'm thinking I need to select the correct server type to get this to work.  Can anyone tell me what I've missed to get the full list?

Comment: Did you create a domain in WLS?

Comment: Yes, and I've verified that I can go in and start the servers in that domain in WLS.